# How do I grep multiple keywords from a file?

Tags: unix, grep

I want to use Unix's [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) function to pull out multiple lines (with different keywords) from a file in one command line.

For example, I have something like:

```
doc-A1-151
file-A2-15646
table-A3-1654
file-B1-15654
doc-B2-15654
table-B3-13546
file-C1-164654
doc-C2-16354
table-C3-13565
```

And I want a sub-version of the file with just the A1, B3, and C2 lines.

How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this post:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2014/03/searching-multiple-strings-in-multiple.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grep allows you to use regular expressions to match patterns within the file using the `-E` flag, or you can use the `egrep` command which is equivalent to `grep -E`:

```
grep -E 'A1|B3|C2' filename
```

or

```
egrep 'A1|B3|C2' filename
```

The vertical bar, `|`, is the OR operator meaning match string A1 or B3 or C2.

Regular expression syntax varies from tool to tool, but generally the syntax is the same. Here is a regex test harness for Ruby that I use frequently to test and build regular expressions: http://rubular.com/r/mJyIMO5hJN

However, any introduction to regular expressions should be prefaced with a warning that they are limited in their capabilities, and the adage is:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 9):

Found it. Put the terms in a text file separated by new lines, then enter that as the pattern to match with the `-f` flag.

pattern_file.txt:

```
A1
B3
C2
```

Command:

```
grep -f pattern_file.txt input_file.txt
```

Comment: grep -i -f <(echo boston; echo advent;echo gita) works but, each argument to echo must be a separate regex, as seen in my example